# Query multiple fields with same value [GraphQL][Amplify]

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm creating an API with AWS Amplify and AppSync GraphQL. I Work on a Tinder like App.

I would like to search the same value in two fields for a Query. I've tried a lot of solutions, but none seems to work.

I have a User `@Model` which is connected to many `Match` via `@connection`

```
type User @model
  @auth(rules: [{allow: public}])

    {
      id: ID!
      email: String!
      password: String
      age: String!
      name: String!
      description: String
      pickupLine: String
      orientation: Orientation!
      gender: Gender! 
      animal: Animal!
      profilePicture: String!
      pictures: [String]!
      location: Location
      numberOfSparksAvailable: Int!
      matchs: [Match]
        @connection(keyName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
      sparks: [Spark]
        @connection(keyName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
    }
```

And I have a Match `@Model` which have a `senderId` field and a `receiverId` field

```
type Match @model
  @auth(rules: [{allow: public}])
  
  @key(name: "byUser", fields: ["receiverId", "senderId"], queryField: "matchByUser")
  @key(name: "bySender", fields: ["senderId"], queryField: "sparkBySender")
  @key(name: "byReceiver", fields: ["receiverId"], queryField: "sparkByReceiver")
    {
      id: ID!
      status: MatchStatus!
      matchType: MatchType
      sender: User! @connection(fields: ["senderId"])
      senderId: ID!
      receiver: User! @connection(fields: ["receiverId"])
      receiverId: ID!
      answerFrom: Answer!
      answerTo: Answer
      chatRoomId: ID!
      chatRoom: ChatRoom!
        @connection(fields: ["chatRoomId"])
      deletedAt: AWSDate
    }
```

And and I don't find any way to make `bySender` `@key` look for both `senderId` and `receiverId`. I want to be able to have all the `Matches` for a `User` whether he's the receiver or the sender.

But when I make a `Query` to `ListUsers` I only get the `Matches` where the `User` is a receiver.

I've also tried to make multiple `@connection` but it is not allowed by `Graphql-transformer`.

I also tried to make an `usersId: [ID!]!` like that

```
type Match @model {
  ...
  usersId: [ID!]!
  users: [User!]!
    @connection(fields: ["usersId"])
  ...
}
```

But It's also not allowed by `graphql-transformer`..

Has anyone a solution to get all the matches for a `User`?

Thanks a lot !